# Find the occurrence of entries for every one hour

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet with a large data. Approximately around 1000 rows and 25 columns. I just need the entries to be calculated per hour.

[image]

I would really appreciate your help. This would make my work a lot easier.

Comment: How I would do this: Add a new column for the hour, then load the sheet into a pivot table and do the aggregation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `COUNTIFS()`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,">="&"6/30/2016 9:56",$B:$B,"<="&"6/30/2016 10:56")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, it worked. Do we have any method to automate this report completely? maybe by using macros? It would be of great help to me

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for something like below,

try the formula given to get the count of 1 hr intervals and finally take the sum

[image]